# Windows Phone 8 Binding

Tags: c#, binding, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8 Pivot application which contains the auto generated `MainViewModel` Binding mechanism.

I have changed the `MainViewModel` class to suit my needs and changed the `MainPage.xaml` markup so that it binds to the correct properties.

All good.

Now - I have a class which calls a Web Service and a call-back method which fires when data is received:

```
private void GetSigns_Completed(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(e.Result))
    {
        var data = sr.ReadToEnd();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SignViewModel>(data);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am not returning or populating anything with the `result` object as I do not know how to do so. The `MainViewModel`'s properties have private `setters`:

```
public ObservableCollection<SignViewModel> Signs { get; private set; }
public ObservableCollection<TweetsViewModel> Tweets { get; private set; }
```

Each of these objects have a `NotifyPropertyChange` event.

So how do I populate the `Signs` and `Tweets` objects and make the whole binding work automatically when retrieving data from a Web Service? How do I make the `UI/Mainpage.xaml` communicate with the Web Service Class and the `MainViewModel` class?

Comment: Does the service return a collection of items or just a single object? What's inside the SignViewModel?

Comment: `Signs.Add(result)` maybe?

Comment: It returns a collection of Signs. So it'd be something like `Signs = result`;

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, I simply changed the `setters` to public for `Signs` and `Tweets`. Once this was in place, the `NotifyPropertyChange` worked it's magic and automatically bound to the View. Magic! I wonder why Microsoft Developers made the setters private .....

Comment: It isn't just setters that are private. Everything automatically defaults to private in C#. Except classes which default to internal

Comment: Yes I know that. I was just wondering why Microsoft made the ViewModel objects private as updating them outside of the ViewModel class is, as I can guess, more than likely.